# Wordpress Featured image is pulling through the first post

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress Featured image is pulling through the first post instead of the featured image of the page.

```
<?php global $post; ?>

<?php
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
?>

<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> );" class="articles-hero-image">
    <h1 class="text-center"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1>
</div>
```

This seems to work on all my other pages however the blog page is a little different it is using the page.php file instead of a template. So this is coming from my default template.

Feels like this should be something easy and silly.

Let me know if you need any additional code but I feel that this is the bit you'll need.